# How to position a div at the bottom of a table-cell when the table cells are filled dynamically

Tags: html, css

I would like to demonstrate my question with the below code snippet :

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.footer {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="50%">
  <tr>

    <td class="container">

      <div class="content">
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              table cell
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              table cell
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              This is a footer
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </td>

    <td class="container">

      <div class="content">

        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              table cell
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              table cell
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              table cell
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              table cell
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              table cell
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>

      <div class="footer">

        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              This is a footer
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>

    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

I have a table with cells(blue) that are filled dynamically with another table (red) and a footer(green). The red tables can contain a variable number of cells. I would like to position the green footer at the bottom of the blue cell, but i have no clue on how to accomplish this. I can't get the content-div's to a same height, because their content is variable. How should i try to approach this? Apologies for the very basic example.

Regards

Comment: You want the blue one on the bottom and the remaining rows centered?

Comment: Is what you want to display using this actual tabular data to begin with? If not, you should not be using tables in the first place. Flexbox can solve stuff like this quite easily.

Comment: i would like all the footers to have to have same positions, at the bottom of the blue container. I tried to set the red div to a height of 90% and the green footer to a height of 10% but I can't seem to change the height of the red container. because the table in the next cell could be way heigher due to its content.

Comment: You should rethink your structure, then use either a table (if that is pertinent) or use a flex or grid display. Turning HTML into a tag soup, is not so digest ;)

Comment: I guess it's tabular data. All the table cells inside the red div should be visible.

Comment: Am i correct when i state that i can't set the height of the red div to 100% of the blue div, because the height of the blue div could be increased in the next cell? Just trying to understand where my logic flaws. Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i get what you are tring to do but I hope this will help you

Try this

```js
    $('.container').each(function(e){
     $(this).css({
           'height': $(this).height() + $(this).find('.footer').height() + 'px'
        })
    })
```

```css
.container{
        border: 2px solid blue;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .content{
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
    
    .footer{
        border: 2px solid green;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="50%">
  <tr>
  
    <td class="container">
     
      <div class="content">
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td >
              table cell
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td >
              table cell
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>
      
      <div class="footer">
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td >
              This is a footer
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
        
    </td> 
  
      <td class="container">

        <div class="content">
        
          <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td>
                table cell
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td >
                table cell
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td >
                table cell
              </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td >
                table cell
              </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td >
                table cell
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        
         </div>
         
         <div class="footer">

           <table border="1" width="100%">
             <tr>
               <td >
                 This is a footer
               </td>
             </tr>
           </table>
          
         </div>

      </td>
   
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

That's one way of doing this. There are more 'elegant' approaches but you will have to rethink your structure.